# JQUERY $.post to PHP page (Internal Server Error 500)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jquery code when I click in an input button launch an event to post updateEstado.php.

Code:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // disable action of the input buttons

    // Get the value of the input fields
   var inputvalue = $(this).attr("value");

    // Send Ajax request to updateEstado.php, with value set as 'input' in the POST data
    $.post('updateEstado2.php', {estado: 'DESACTIVAT', codigo: '38'});


    alert(inputvalue);          

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php   
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] <> ''){

                include("db_tools.php"); 

                $conn = dbConnect("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  


                $estado = $_POST['estado'];

                $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

                echo "<br>Estado: " + $estado;
                echo "<br>Codigo: " + $codigo;

        /*      
                $query = "UPDATE produccion.ma_producto SET estado={$estado} WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 

                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

                if ($result == TRUE) {
                    header('Location: produccio.php');
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                }   */

                $conn->close();

        } else{
            ?><p>La sessió no està activa, si us plau ingresa <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
<?php   
        }?>
```

This code working fine because I show the alert message only when I clic in a button doesn't launch to post updateEstado.php in the debug console of the browser show this error message:

[image]

I have tried a php page with only `echo "test";` but it doesn't work too, it show the same error message.

Please Could you help me?

Comment: What is written in `updateEstado2.php`? Please post it too.

Comment: The first thing you should to is to check your error logs to find the actual error message.

Comment: tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log your error is there

Comment: check your webserver

Comment: that's a server error, not client side

Comment: The error is in the PHP code `updateEstado2.php` So show us that code

Comment: Here's a SO post on how to turn on error reporting/debugging your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 500 errors are normaly so serious, you dont get much from error reporting

Comment: I have to get out of this rabbit hole now @RiggsFolly

Comment: Been gone a while already @Fred-ii- See you at the next one

Comment: *Arrivederci!* @RiggsFolly

Comment: run php file from link withen browser and see the output. So when your php file run without an error then try ajax

Comment: I update the code with the updateEstado.php but I do not think that the problem because I tried with other blank php file and it's the same error.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have seen the error in the logfile and it's solved! The problem was a function :(

Answer (score 1):

In your php use

```
echo "<br>Estado: " . $estado;
echo "<br>Codigo: " . $codigo;
```

Not

```
echo "<br>Estado: " + $estado;
echo "<br>Codigo: " + $codigo;
```

And `$_SESSION['username'] != ''`